# Data Binding And Cross-Thread Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, thread-safety

Trying to get clear about flaw in this code:

**Scenario 1:**
This scenario uses data binding and causes the very well known ***cross-thread exception*** in the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method in the `PriceSimulator` class.

**Scenario 2:**
This scenario solves the problem by subscribing to the `PropertyChanged` event of `PriceSimulator`, eliminates the cross-thread issue but has to avoid data binding altogether.

Assuming Scenario 1 was the intended scenario and assuming one has no knowledge of the inner workings of `PriceSimulator` and just wanted to bind to the `Price` property, what is the core issue here?

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PriceSimulator simul;
    Action labelAction;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelAction = new Action(SetLabel);

        simul = new PriceSimulator(5, 1000);

        //Scenario 1:
        //Use data binding and get Cross-Thread exception
        //label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", simul, "Price");

        //Scenario 2:
        //This works fine
        //Subscribe to PropertyChanged event
        simul.PropertyChanged += task_PropertyChanged;

        simul.Start();
    }

    //Scenario 2:
    void task_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(labelAction);
        else SetLabel();
    }
    private void SetLabel()
    {
        label1.Text = simul.Price.ToString("C2"); 
    }
}
```

PriceSimulator.cs:

```
public class PriceSimulator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 

    private int max, delay, priceValue;
    private Timer timer;

    public PriceSimulator(int max, int delay)
    {
        this.max = max;
        this.delay = delay;
    }
    public void Start()
    {
        timer = new Timer(CallbackProc, null, delay, delay);
    }
    private void CallbackProc(object obj)
    {
        if (++Price >= max)
            timer.Dispose();
    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        try
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public int Price 
    {
        get
        {
            return priceValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (priceValue != value)
            {
                priceValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have the current context in your PriceSimulator class:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Now that you have the context, you can use it to update the UI:

```
 _context.Post(delegate
                {
                    if (++Price >= max)
                       timer.Dispose();
                }, null);
```